# New undocumented EKCalendarType found in calendars

Tags: eventkit, xcode10, ios12

In Xcode 10 with iOS 12 SDK, when I retrieve all event calendars from EventKit, seems like there is a new type of calendar, with `EKCalendarType` rawValue as **5**. This can be reproduced in the simulator and on the device.

Any idea what this is? Is it possible to have private API on an enum case, so that it bypasses the exhaust check?

```
let calendars = store.calendars(for: .event)
calendars.forEach { (calendar) in
    print(calendar.title) // => Found in Mail
    print(calendar.type.rawValue) // => 5
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of a bad bug. If your code switches on the `calendar.type` and the `rawValue` is 5, the app crashes because it can't initialize a case with that value. When I run it in the simulator, the relevant calendar has `calendar.source.sourceType = .birthdays`.

So to summarize there is a new system-generated calendar: `"Found in Mail" sourceType: .birthdays, calendar.type.rawValue: 5`

Comment: I just filed a radar for this.